# working with BeautifulSoup - defining the entities for getting all the data of the target page - perhaps panda would solve this even better

Tags: python, pandas, csv, beautifulsoup

i am in the mid of a task with BeautifulSoup - the awesome python-library for all things scraping.  what is aimed: i want to get the data out of this page: https://schulfinder.kultus-bw.de  note; its a public page for finding all schools in a certain region.

so a typical dataset will look like:

```
Adresse Name
Adresse 2
Kategorie
Straße
PLZ und Ort
Tel 1
Tel 2
Mail
```

well i think - with the usage of Python i will go like so:

firstly i will have to send a request to the URL and get the page HTML content:

```
url = 'https://schulfinder.kultus-bw.de'
response = requests.get(url)
html_content = response.content
```

afterwards - the next step i will have to create a BeautifulSoup object and find the HTML elements that contain the school names:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
schools = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'dropdown-item'})
Extract the school names from the HTML elements and store them in a list:
school_names = [school.text.strip() for school in schools]
```

and subsequently i need to print the list of school names:

```
print(school_names)
```

well the complete code would look like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://schulfinder.kultus-bw.de'
response = requests.get(url)
html_content = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
schools = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'dropdown-item'})
school_names = [school.text.strip() for school in schools]

print(school_names)
```

but i need to have all the dataset -

```
Adresse Name
Adresse 2
Kategorie
Straße
PLZ und Ort
Tel 1
Tel 2
Mail
```

best thing would be to output it in CSV-formate; well if i would be a bit more familiar with Python then i would run this little code and would work with pandas - i guess that pandas would be much easier to work on that kind of thing.

..

**update:** see some images of the page:

[image]

[image]

**update 2** i try to run this in google-colab: i get the following errors..
**question:** do i need to install some of the packages into collab!?

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Pool
from string import ascii_lowercase as chars
from itertools import product
```

do i need to take care for the preliminaries in google-colab?!

see the **errorlog that i have gotten**

```
100%|██████████| 676/676 [00:00<00:00, 381711.03it/s]
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

5 frames
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'branches'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'branches'
```

**end** of **errorlog** - gotten from **google-colab:**

see **below** the **errors** - that i have gotten from **Anaconda:**

Anaconda: logs at home

```
100%|██████████| 676/676 [00:00<00:00, 9586.24it/s]
0it [00:00, ?it/s]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3628             try:
-> 3629                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3630             except KeyError as err:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'branches'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_27106/2163647892.py in <module>
     36     df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
     37 
---> 38     df = df.explode('branches')
     39     df = df.explode('trades')
     40     df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('branches').apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('branch_')], axis=1)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in explode(self, column, ignore_index)
   8346         df = self.reset_index(drop=True)
   8347         if len(columns) == 1:
-> 8348             result = df[columns[0]].explode()
   8349         else:
   8350             mylen = lambda x: len(x) if is_list_like(x) else -1

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3503             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3504                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3505             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506             if is_integer(indexer):
   3507                 indexer = [indexer]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3629                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3630             except KeyError as err:
-> 3631                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3632             except TypeError:
   3633                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'branches'
```

**conclusio:** i am trying to find out more - i am eagerly trying to get more insights and to run the code ...

many thanks for all the help - ahd for encouraging to dive in all things python... - this is awesme.
have a great day...

Comment: I don't see the element with class "dropdown-item" on the URL. Is the URL correct?

Comment: hi there -  good day dear Andrej  first of all : many many thanks for the quick reply - its awesome to hear from you: see this is the correct url: https://schulfinder.kultus-bw.de

Comment: When I click on the "Suchen" I get back 500 results. But I suspect there are lot more.

Comment: there must be more than 10 000 results ... see the options that you can choose 
first you add a town - then you can see on the right of the town - a option to enter a radius - around this town - and subsequently  you can choose from various school-types - like elementary school and higher school etc  etx.

see the images above... - Andrej - you are an awesomy pythonist - and i am pretty sure that you can help here. A output into a dataset - (not printed to screen but saved as a dataset - this would be awesome.

Comment: So, you need to get all ~10000 results or just results in one town ("ort") ?

Comment: hi  i need to have all the schools in the country called Baden Württemberg - which is one of the 17 countries of Germany.  And to start the search by choosing a town is only one search approach - in fact the only one that i tried - .... perhaps there are other approaches too... it would be a pleasure to have all the schools that are "available"..

Comment: off for a few hours . ill be back  in few hours... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: When you enter `aa` and click "Suchen" the server returns all items that contains "aa". So you can try all combinations (`aa`, `ab`, `ac`, ...) to get all school IDs and then get info about all schools:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Pool
from string import ascii_lowercase as chars
from itertools import product

api_url1 = 'https://schulfinder.kultus-bw.de/api/schools?distance=&outposts=1&owner=&school_kind=&term={term}&types=&work_schedule='
api_url2 = 'https://schulfinder.kultus-bw.de/api/school?uuid={uuid}'

def get_school(term):
    try:
        return requests.get(api_url1.format(term=term)).json()
    except:
        return []

def get_school_detail(uuid):
    return requests.get(api_url2.format(uuid=uuid)).json()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = [''.join(t) for t in product(chars, chars)]
    # you can try also to get all 3-character combinations (this will yield 4476 results (but the first step will take longer)
    # l = [''.join(t) for t in product(chars, chars, chars)]

    all_data = []
    all_uuids = set()

    with Pool(processes=8) as pool:
        for result in tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(get_school, l), total=len(l)):
            for item in result:
                all_uuids.add(item['uuid'])

    with Pool(processes=16) as pool:
        for r in tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(get_school_detail, all_uuids), total=len(all_uuids)):
            all_data.append(r)

    df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)

    df = df.explode('branches')
    df = df.explode('trades')
    df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('branches').apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('branch_')], axis=1)
    df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('trades').apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('trade_')], axis=1)

    print(df.head())

    df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

This will get info about all 4461 schools and saves data to `data.csv`:

```
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 676/676 [00:38<00:00, 17.63it/s]
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 4461/4461 [00:22<00:00, 194.86it/s]
  outpost_number                                                 name               street house_number postcode        city            phone              fax                              email                                   website tablet_tranche tablet_platform tablet_branches tablet_trades       lat      lng  official  branch_branch_id branch_acronym branch_description_long  trade_0 trade_trade_id trade_description
0              0  Schule am Schlosspark Realschule und Werkrealschule  Schussenrieder Str.           25    88326   Aulendorf   +4975259238102   +4975259238104  poststelle@04160556.schule.bwl.de         http://www.schuleamschlosspark.de           None            None            None          None  47.95760  9.63881         0             15110             RS              Realschule      NaN            NaN               NaN
0              0  Schule am Schlosspark Realschule und Werkrealschule  Schussenrieder Str.           25    88326   Aulendorf   +4975259238102   +4975259238104  poststelle@04160556.schule.bwl.de         http://www.schuleamschlosspark.de           None            None            None          None  47.95760  9.63881         0             14210            WRS          Werkrealschule      NaN            NaN               NaN
1              0              Schauenburg-Schule Grundschule Urloffen      Schauenburgstr.            4    77767  Appenweier     +49780597236    +497805914396  poststelle@04155676.schule.bwl.de  http://www.schauenburgschule-urloffen.de           None            None            None          None  48.56460  7.97361         0             12110             GS             Grundschule      NaN            NaN               NaN
2              0                      Klosterwiesenschule Grundschule            Boschstr.            1    88255      Baindt  +49750294114132  +49750294114139  poststelle@04139725.schule.bwl.de               http://www.baindt.de/schule           None            None            None          None  47.84319  9.65829         0             12110             GS             Grundschule      NaN            NaN               NaN
3              0                       Montessori-Grundschule Nußdorf          Zum Laugele            7    88662  Überlingen     +49755165620             None  poststelle@04117742.schule.bwl.de        http://www.grundschule-nussdorf.de           None            None            None          None  47.75325  9.19516         0             12110             GS             Grundschule      NaN            NaN               NaN

...
```

screenshot from LibreOffice:

[image]

Comment: many thanks dear Andrej - so awesome - you saved my day.   This is so outstanding cool - i am very glad...!

Comment: hi Andrej - again me;: i have tried to run this in google collab and have got back some errormesages - see above the threastart-posting - where i have added an update. Look forward to hear from you... regards

Comment: @malaga The IP address on Google Collab might be blocked by the server. When you run your script from the home it works?

Comment: hello dear Andrej - i tried to run the script from my noteook ( in Anaconda ) -see above!!... in my humble view - the errors are nearly the same. Do you have any idea how to get more insights - l...look forward to hear fom you  - note: i will continue to get the script up and running here.... - many many thanks for all you do!!! you are a great coder!!!

Comment: @malaga Try to `import requests` (I forgot to include it in the code). Also you can try to remove the `try/except` clause and see what's the error (if any).

Comment: wow - many thanks - with adding import requests  it works very good .... even in colab.... 
many many thanks